# Empty line output while using Popen with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get information output from the command:

```
ffmpeg -i 2019-04-22_16-45-14.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.png -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=99:32" -f null -
```

When trying this command in command line - the info is there, but when I try to use `Popen` - nothing (None, None)

I've tried subprocess, and tried `os.popen` earlier.

```
command = 'ffmpeg -i 2019-04-22_16-45-14.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.png -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=99:32" -f null -'
subproc = subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), shell=True)
x = subproc.communicate()
print(x)
```

Comment: be careful, "info" from ffmpeg comes back in the stderr stream FWIW...

Comment: thank you! I actually just solved the problem with subprocess.check_output! :)

Comment: feel free to add an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

This code save all results at file out.txt. If have any error, it go to err.txt:

```
with open('out.txt','w+') as fout:
    with open('err.txt','w+') as ferr:
        proc = subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', '20200522_0755.mp4', '-r', '1', '-loop', '1', '-i', 'livre.jpg', '-an', '-filter_complex', 'blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=89:32', '-f', 'null', '-'],stdout=fout,stderr=ferr)
        # reset file to read from it
        fout.seek(0)
        # save output (if any) in variable
        output=fout.read()
        # reset file to read from it
        ferr.seek(0) 
        # save errors (if any) in variable
        errors = ferr.read()
```